# Yocto: patch kernel module Makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, yocto, kernel-module

I have a Linux kernel for NXP i.MX6. There are some capture kernel modules in `/driver/media/platform/mxc/capture`.

One of the files called `mxc_v4l2_capture.c`. I had to change this file for using it with my own new kernel driver.

I created a repository with my driver and the sources for `mxc_v4l2_capture`. Then I made a new Yocto recipe in my layer `recipies-kernel -> kernel-modules->my-kernel-module.bb`

Yocto can build these two kernel modules (`my-kernel-module.ko` and `mxc_v4l2_capture.ko`).

Okay, now there is a problem because the kernel recipe already builds the `mxc_v4l2_capture` module. Therefore I want to manipulate the `Makefile` for the original kernel modules and exclude the `make` of `mxc_v4l2_capture`.

I have created the patch but I don't know how to use the patch with Yocto. Where to place it and how can I call it?

Normally I put a patch into a `.bbappend` file and finish but I don't know the name of the recipe that build the kernel modules.

It would be great if there is a way without manipulating this `Makefile`.

Is there a way to solve this with my kernel module recipe?

Answer (score 1):

`mxc_v4l2_capture.c` is in-tree kernel driver. If you want to change the in-tree driver code and compile, it's highly recommended to patch the kernel and compile the kernel with usual recipe.

Having additional bitbake recipe for the in-tree kernel module is not necessary. To patch the kernel and compile, you can use `.bbappend` or `.bb` itself. For example,

if you have `recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stable_4.19.75.bb` in your Yocto BSP layer, you can add the patch to `SRC_URI` as below.

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}-${PV}:"
SRC_URI += "file://mxc_v4l2_capture.patch"
```

Now, you create `recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stable-4.19.75/` and copy the `mxc_v4l2_capture.patch` file inside.

Or if you don't have permission or not possible to modify the Kernel recipe in BSP layer, you can create `.bbappend` in your custom layer. For the above example, you can create `linux-stable_4.19.75.bbappend` (specific version) or `linux-stable_%.bbappend` (any version). Then place the same content as mentioned above.

Yocto supports various patch formats, refer [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-tasks-patch) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836721/yocto-change-kernel-version-and-select-drivers/58857748#58857748) answer I wrote some days ago. The steps are basically the same. Using

```
devtool modify virtual/kernel
```

will create a working copy in build/workspace where you can do the work you want. Commiting those changes to the local branch and running

```
devtool finish linux-mainline <path-to-your-layer>
```

will create a .bbappend file with the patches already created and put to the correct location for you.

If you want to learn how to do it manually follow the advice @Parthiban gave.